# Dispatch on return type in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's say I have the following case classes:

```
case class Category(name: String)

case class Record(price: Double, description: String, category: Category)

case class Sale(price: Double, qty: Int, dateOfSale: Date, category: Category)
```

I want to invoke a method that returns a list of `Sale` or `Record` based on category. The only difference is the return type. So rather than `findSalesByCategory` and `findRecordsByCategory` I want something like:

```
def findByCategory[T](category: Category): List[T] = classOf[T] match {
  case c if c == classOf[Sale]   => findRecordsByCategory(category)
  case c if c == classOf[Record] => findSalesByCategory(category)
}
```

Obviously this fails compilation with:

```
error: class type required but T found
    def findByCategory[T](category: Category): List[T] = classOf[T] match {
                                                    ^
```

Is there an approach that works?

Comment: This is a good use case for type classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use typetags:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def findByCategory[T: TypeTag](category: Category): List[T] = {

   typeOf[T] match {
       case t if t =:= typeOf[Sale]   => findSalesByCategory(category)
       case t if t =:= typeOf[Record] => findRecordsByCategory(category)
   }
}
```

Comment: It won't work - `TypeTag#tpe` returns instance of `Type`, but `classOf` returns `Class[_]`, and they are not the same. You can check it easily in Scala REPL.

Comment: You also probably should write `typeOf[Sale]`, not `typeOf(Sale)` - it is a type parameter.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev yes. I had it correct in my editor, typed incorrectly here. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post declarations for `findSalesByCategory` and `findRecordsByCategory`? The obvious `def findRecordsByCategory(c: Category): List[Record] = ???` and `def findSalesByCategory(c: Category): List[Sale] = ???` don't seem to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Because your categories are not generic, `ClassTag` will also suffice:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def findByCategory[T: ClassTag](category: Category): List[T] = {
  classTag[T] match {
    case c if c == classTag[Sale] => findSalesByCategory(category)
    case c if c == classTag[Record] => findRecordByCategory(category)
  }
}
```

This will work when subtypes of `T` you're matching on are not parameterized; in that case you'll have to use `TypeTag`s.

There is a way to simplify matching a bit. You can save `ClassTag`s or `Class`es into a `val` and match on it:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

val saleClass = classOf[Sale]
val recordClass = classOf[Record]
def findByCategory[T: ClassTag](category: Category): List[T] = {
  classTag[T].runtimeClass match {
    case `saleClass` => findSalesByCategory(category)
    case `recordClass` => findRecordByCategory(category)
  }
}
```